# How to Calculate 3 Phase Voltage & Current from Power (VA)?

Tags: matlab, simulink, subsystem

I am trying to develop a MATLAB Simulink model that will help me study the load of my department. 
The model works, however one of the blocks goes right over my head when it comes to understanding, as I used the internet to help me with it.

Here is the main block:
[image]

1. The Scope Displays the Voltage, Current & Power
2. The "dept01" block inputs the data from .csv file and contains only [Time,Power].

Here is what goes inside of the "Electrical Department" Block:

[image]

I have no problem understanding this part, I'm simply splitting the total power into three portions. 
NOTE: I am also assuming that ultimately Q=0 so Total Power = Real Power

[image]

This is the Second Step of the "Electrical Department" block which I cannot understand in any way. Maybe my concepts are weak but this part makes no sense to me.

Can someone please explain it to me that how is the block calculating Voltage & Current using just the Power??? Also how does it imitate the function of a Load so that the Energy Meter sees it as a load?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Load can be emulated by connecting a current source in series with the voltage source as it is seen the diagram. In your case, the controlled current source has been used. It also looks like the dependent current source is derived from the voltage. I request you to give the details of relational operator used and the sigma block. Without which you can not derive the relation ship. If the current is dependent on the voltage like the case, voltage and current can be calculated simply from the power.